# Proof of: $f_{n}^{2} = f_{n-1}f_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

So I'm going over some examples  of recursion and Fibonacci Sequences for my quiz tomorrow and I'm a bit lost after a certain point.

Prove $f_{n}^{2} = f_{n-1}f_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}$ $n\geq 2$

Basis Step: P(2)

$f_{2}^{2} = f_{2-1}f_{2+1}+(-1)^{n+1}$

$(1)^{2} = f_{1}f_{3}+(-1)^{3}$

$(1)^{2} = (1)(2)+(-1)$

$1 = 1$

Induction Step: Assume P(n) is true, Prove P(n+1), that is, show: $f_{n+1}^{2} = f_{n}(f_{n}+f_{n+1})+(-1)^{(n+2)}$

$$\begin{align}
f_{n}f_{n+2}+(-1)^{n+2} & = f_{n}(f_{n+1}+f_{n})+(-1)^{n+2} \\
 & = f_{n}f_{n+1}+f_{n}^{2}+(-1)^{n+2} \\
 & = f_{n}f_{n+1}+[f_{n-1}f_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}]+(-1)^{n+2} \\
\end{align}$$

What do I do after this step? I'm a bit lost...

Comment: It seems like you started with A=B and ended up showing that A=B. Try assuming the hypothesis P(n), and start developing the left hand side of P(n+1). $f_{n+1}^{2} = f_{n+1}(f_n+f_{n-1})= f_{n+1}f_n + f_{n+1}f_{n-1}$ and now use the hypothesis to replace the second term. A little algebra and you are done!

Comment: @Nocturne When you say "hypothesis" I presume you're referring to the given equation (the one used in the basis step) but how can you replace the second term when you don't have $(-1)^{n+1}$ to complete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your inductive step you started out by assuming
$$f_{n+1}^2=f_nf_{n+2}+(-1)^{n+2}\ .$$
But this is what you are trying to prove, so your argument, even if "successful", will be circular and therefore wrong.

A better way would be to start with **the RHS only** of this equation and prove it equals the LHS.  You could begin
$$f_nf_{n+2}+(-1)^{n+2}=f_n(f_{n+1}+f_n)+(-1)^{n+2}\ .$$
See if you can take it from here.  Remember that at some stage you will have to use the assumed formula for $f_n^2$.

Comment: So I've reached $f_{n}f_{n+2}+(-1)^{n+2} = f_{n}f_{n+1}+f_{n-1}f_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+2}$ and have no idea what to do again

Comment: @TaiM. $(-1)^{n + 1} + (-1)^{n + 2} = ?$. Now what happens if you factor out $f_{n+1}$?

Comment: @ChantryCargill what's funny is that I knew that equaled zero but had NO idea what that meant. I think it's time I took a break.  Thank you and David both! Really appreciate it.